# onPressed functions not triggered inside Stack Layout Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a carousel, two iconButtons in a Positioned Layout, gridView and 2 other positioned layouts All Inside A Stack Layout.

The onPressed() functions on the iconButtons specifically or on any of the elements general do not get triggered. I figured out that the issue is because of the Parent Stack Layout because when place them outside of it the onPressed works.

I need the Stack Layout for the design so im wondering if there is an alternative for it.

Here's an example of the code:

```
child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            carouselSlider = CarouselSlider(
                              height: 270.0,
                              initialPage: 0,
                              viewportFraction: 1.0,
                              aspectRatio: 1.0,
                              enlargeCenterPage: false,
                              autoPlay: true,
                              reverse: false,
                              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 2),
                              autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                  Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                              pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              onPageChanged: (index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  current = index;
                                });
                              },
                              items: carouselImages.map((i) {
                                return Builder(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return Container(
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                            // behavior:
                                            //     HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                              i,
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                            onTap: () {
                                              // Navigator.push<Widget>(
                                              //   context,
                                              //   MaterialPageRoute(
                                              //     builder: (context) => ImageScreen(i),
                                              //   ),
                                              // );
                                            }));
                                  },
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children:
                                  map<Widget>(carouselImages, (index, url) {
                                return Container(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                  height: 10.0,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: current == index
                                        ? Color.fromRGBO(221, 40, 42, 0.7)
                                        : Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 5,
                        top: 10,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(221, 40, 42, 0.7),
                          iconSize: 20.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('Clicked');
                            scaffolddKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap all of your widgets that are not supposed to receive tap events in IgnorePointer widget.

If your CarouselSlider is not supposed to receive tap events then wrap it and all other widgets that are not supposed to receive tap events in IgnorePointer widget.

Comment: Okaay i just figured it out! it worked but still only the iconButtons work while a gridview under the carousel with an inkwell does not work because i wrapped it in an ignorePointer! is there a solution for this??